# How can I run PHP Service on Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: php, websocket, google-cloud-platform, phpwebsocket

Is this possible to run the WebSocket service in Google Cloud App Engine, not for Compute Engine for PHP.

I need to run below service:

```
php service.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not currently appear to be possible.

WebSocket support for Google App Engine [is in beta for Python, Java, and Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-websockets-and-session-affinity). It is not listed as supported for the PHP runtime.

Comment: Thank your comment, but can you guide me how can I open the project in the command line to going that file and run my command is possible?.

Answer (score 0):

the Websockets feature in App Engine Flexible environment works for all languages, even though only three are documented.